# Error running gzserver from an ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu-16.04

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

So I'm trying to run a Gazebo server from an Ubuntu 16.04 instance, with no GUI.

when I run `gzserver --verbose` it outputs my ip settings (port 11345) and then this:

`[Err] [RenderEngine.cc:726] Can't open display:`

`[Wrn] [RenderEngine.cc:93] Unable to create X window. Rendering will be disabled`

`[Wrn] [RenderEngine.cc:293] Cannot initialize render engine since render path type is NONE. Ignore this warning ifrendering has been turned off on purpose.`

If I try and connect to it from another machine the client will output `Exception sending a message` for a while and then both the client and the server will output something like `Aborted (core dumped)`.

Also, I tried running the server from an Ubuntu instance with a GUI. I didn't get the same `[Err]` and `[Wrn]` messages, but it still did the whole `core dumped` stuff.

Question 1: Can you run gzserver without a GUI?

Question 2: Any help on how to run a server like this? I haven't seen a tutorial on this exactly.

Thanks much!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/17899/error-running-gzserver-from-an-ubuntu-server./) by [billybilly](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4123/billybilly/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-11-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

It is possible to run gazebo without a physical screen but you probably want a display in order to get rendering capabilities. You can use the graphic card headless or launch a virtual display, check the [options to configure headless gazebo](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/14625/running-a-camera-sensor-headless/).

---

Originally posted by [Jose Luis Rivero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/152/jose-luis-rivero/) with karma: 1485 on 2017-11-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1